# How to avoid SQL Injection with Rails #order method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, postgis, code-injection

I haven't been able to find any resources online about prevent SQL injections when using `#order`. There's no trouble using `?`-placeholders for the where-clause, but it doesn't seem to work for the order-clause.

Here's an example:

```
query = Foo.where("ST_DISTANCE(coords, ?) < ?", point, distance)
           # The line below works:
           .order("ST_DISTANCE(coords, ST_GeomFromText('#{point}'))")
           # This line doesn't work:
           .order("ST_DISTANCE(coords, ST_GeomFromText(?))", point)
```

Just to be clear: the line that doesn't work returns a `PGError` which logs `ST_DISTANCE(coords, ST_GeomFromText(?))` literally.

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to pass something like `POINT(-71.064544 42.28787)` in GET/POST params? I saw example here http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html

I think better to

```
order("ST_DISTANCE(coords, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(%f %f))" % [lat, lon])
```

`%` is shorthand for [Kernel::sprintf](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sprintf)

Comment: Should be `[lon, lat]` (i.e. X Y)

Answer (score 0):

The [QueryMethod](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb) `order` calls `preprocess_order_args` which expects it will just be given a list of fields and optionally directions.

One option would be to call `sanitize_sql` which can be done from within an `ActiveRecord` class method:

```
# Inside Foo class
def self.order_by_distance(point)
  order(sanitize_sql(["ST_DISTANCE(coords, ST_GeomFromText(?))", point]))
end
```